# Is there a Chrome Extension API way to navigate to the homepage programmatically?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there a way in a Chrome Extension to programmatically do what the "Open the homepage" button does in Chrome and navigate to the homepage (or at least retrieve the homepage URL) ?

Comment: Excellent question. But I don't think there is a solution. I'm not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 2):

A quick look through all available Chrome APIs shows that there is no such API method.

Some searching and testing suggests that there is no way to do that in Chrome with JavaScript in general, either.

So most likely you can't do this.

---

For the sake of logical completeness, your extension can [*override* the homepage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/settings_override). However, if there are 2 extensions than do that the last installed wins, and you can't test for that.

Comment: P.S. It makes sense to request that as a feature. If you do it at https://crbug.com, please comment here with the issue links afterwards.